# Parsing JSON and save locally

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I'm working on an iOS application written in Objective-C and I'm almost done, except for one thing:

I'm parsing a JSON into a tableview, and I want to store the data locally in the app. But I don't know the best way of doing this. Each row has an image, a title, description, and a link. I have different tabs with different JSON.

(I don't want to parse the JSON every time the app opens up, I want to check if something new has been added to the JSON and THEN parse it again. But for now I'm just happy if I can manage to save the data from the JSON locally)

I've been struggling with this for a while now and I really need some help. This is the last thing that I need to fix before the app is ready for App Store.

Don't know if you need to see any code, but I post it anyway so you might get a better understanding of what I'm doing.

Code for parsing json:

```
 jsonData_ = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.myUrl.se/json/%@.json", _whatState];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: urlString];
    NSURLRequest *urlReq = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: url];
    NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest: urlReq delegate:self];


-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection*) connection{

    //NSLog(@"Succeeded! Recieved %d bytes of data", [jsonData_ length]);
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *items = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: jsonData_ options: kNilOptions error: &error];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDesc = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"title" ascending:YES]copy];
    NSMutableArray *sortedItems = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject: sortDesc];
    sortedItems = [[items sortedArrayUsingDescriptors: sortedItems] copy];

    if(!error)
    {
        tableData_ = sortedItems;
        tableImgs_ = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: tableData_ copyItems: YES];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
        jsonIsFinishedLoading = TRUE;

    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"ERROR");
    }
}
```

Code for my tableview:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"listItem";
    TSCustomCell *cell = (TSCustomCell*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell setSelectedBackgroundView:selectedCellBgColorView];


    if(jsonIsFinishedLoading)
    {
        NSDictionary *row = [tableData_ objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
        NSString *title = [row objectForKey:@"title"];

        cell.url = [row objectForKey:@"url"];
        UIFont *defaultFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Edmondsans-Bold" size:12.0];

        [cell.listItemLbl setText: title];
        [cell.listItemLbl setFont:defaultFont];


        if([[tableImgs_ objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isMemberOfClass: [UIImage class]])
            {
                [cell.listItemImage setImage: [tableImgs_ objectAtIndex: indexPath.row]];
            }
            else
            {

                UIActivityIndicatorView *loadingSymbol = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
                loadingSymbol.frame = cell.listItemImage.frame;
                [cell addSubview: loadingSymbol];
                [loadingSymbol startAnimating];


                dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0ul);

                dispatch_async(queue, ^{


                    NSString *url = [row objectForKey: @"image"];

                    if([url isEqualToString: @""])
                    {
                        url = @"http://www.myUrl.se/images/standard.png";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        url = [row objectForKey: @"image"];
                    }

                    NSURL *imgUrl = [NSURL URLWithString: url];
                    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: imgUrl];
                    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: imageData];

                    if(image != nil)
                    {
                        [tableImgs_ replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:image];
                        NSLog(@"tableImgs != nil");

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        NSLog(@"tableImgs = nil");
                        [cell.listItemImage setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"standard_transp.png"]];
                    }

                    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                        [loadingSymbol removeFromSuperview];
                        [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationNone];


                    });  
                }); //end dispatch_async
            }
        }
    }


    return cell;

}
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

If i understood you correct - you can save your data with JSOn into user defaults by this code

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:jsonData_ forKey:@"myData"];
```

If you are parsing json - you have data with it

when you want to get it

```
jsonData_ = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey: @"myData"];
```

Comment: Don't you want to save `items` or `sortedItems`, rather than the raw data?

Comment: But the thing is, i have more than one json, with different data. Can i save more than one JSON in NSUserDefaults?

Comment: Yes, you can. Different json - different keys in userDefaults

Comment: Ofcourse, thank you Arthur! How much data can the userDefault store?

Comment: I do not think that keeping a large number of data in the UserDefaults is a good idea. If there is much data it's better to use CoreData.

Answer (score -2):

[Here's a useful tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1914/how-to-save-your-app-data-with-nscoding-and-nsfilemanager) on using the [NSCoding Protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) and [NSFileManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to save objects to disk. If you create an object for each row, you'll be able to save them.

You could also use this approach to save the JSON itself, or you can store it in the [user defaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

```
# Saving
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:jsonData forKey:@"json data"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]; // Generally happens automatically, but if this might happen close to backgrounding you'll want this

# Loading
jsonData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"json data"];
```

Answer (score -3):

Use AFNetworking to acheive this. Its easier, faster and much better than NSURLConnection.

Read more here:[AFNetworking](http://www.raywenderlich.com/30445/afnetworking-crash-course)

Comment: Will AFNetworking help me with my problem to store the data locally?

Comment: Yes, definitely!!. just go through the article